# How to use a specific analyser in ElasticSearch when using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run a specific search in ElasticSearch using the Java API. It works well, but I need to use a snowball analyser.

What I really want is to implement this kind of search:
http://localhost:9200/myindex/myfeed/_search?q=myterm:myvalue&analyzer=myanalyzer
using Java API.

I'm using a TransportClient with many different types of queries (filtered, match all, text). I'm running multiple search queries in bulk.

I don't see anything relevant to analysers in the SearchRequestBuilder. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your request would translate into

```
    client.prepareSearch("myindex", "myfeed")
            .setQuery(
                    QueryBuilders.queryString("myterm:myvalue")
                            .analyzer("myanalyzer")
            )
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

In general, when you are running into problems translating Rest API requests into JavaAPI requests, take a look at the Rest???Action class, where ??? is the name of your request. For example, if you would like to learn more about building Search requests, take a look at [RestSearchAction.java](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/04a138db5ddf3f28ffd0d7f81054b05c3c6aa02d/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/search/RestSearchAction.java#L154). You can also find many java API examples in the elasticsearch [integration tests](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/tree/master/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/test/integration/search/basic).

Comment: Thank you. I realized that not every QueryBuilder have the `analyzer()` function implemented. I tried to be as generic as possible, but it works if I specify the analyzer while building appropriate queries (textQuery, in my case). Thank you.